# How to detect negative number in Zend Framework Router Regex

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have the following .ini configuration working fine for positive integers, but not negative integers.

```
routes.nd.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex"
routes.nd.route = "news/(\d+)/d"
routes.nd.defaults.controller = "news"
routes.nd.defaults.action = "display"
routes.nd.map.id = 1
```

How to make it detect negative integers? Apparently `\d+` ignores negative numbers.

Can't find this in ZF docs.

regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Negative values:
"news/(-\d+)/d"
```

Answer (score 1):

Postitive or Negative values:

```
"news/(-?\d+)/d"
```